# UITableViewCell Highlights & Effects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, highlighting

So I have a `tableview` with 8 cells containing 8 `uitextfields` as subviews to each cell. It's basically like a form that the user needs to fill up and I want some effects while the user starts typing.

When `TextFieldDidBeginEditing` method gets called, I want that corresponding `UITableViewCell` to be highlighted, and all other UITableViewCells to be sort-of 'Dimmed' . This effect makes the User Focus on the particular textField he is typing in, and I am trying to implement this in my code.

Is this possible ? I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this EFFECT !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray*cells = [_regTable visibleCells];

    UITableViewCell*currentcell = [_regTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (UITableViewCell*cell in cells)
    {
        if ([cell isEqual:currentCell] == NO) //You'll have to think on how to distinguish a selected cell from an unselected one - if you go the default way then that's how its done
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
            cell.alpha = 0.5;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
        else
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
            cell.alpha = 1.0;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Thanks a lot for the input. I can understand the context of the `alpha`, and seems like a good place to start. From your code, would this affect the entire uitableviewcell ?

Comment: A `UITableViewCell` is a `UIView`. So you can just go `cell.alpha` and set the desired value, but I discourage this as it'll have some crazy effects on the cell as it'll look a bit odd. :P

Comment: Just added a nice `UIView` fade animation with it too so it's less jerky. Give it a try!

Comment: So yes, Thanks for the input David. Definitely a good answer. But I am looking for something more here. Let me know if you can help me with this. I want the whole uitableviewcell to look super bright, while all other tableviewcells look very dim.

Comment: I've edited the code to dim the whole cell. Finetune the `alpha` values with a value between 0 and 1 and see how it goes!

Comment: That was awesome !! Thanks a lot buddy. Really awesome answer. This helps only when I touch the uitableviewcell, and not the uitextfield inside each tableview cells. But yes, I Got the Idea ! And I really thank you for your time !

Comment: For textfields, have a look into its delegate methods! :)